# fbprophet Error : AttributeError: 'StanModel' object has no attribute 'fit_class'AttributeError: 'StanModel' object has no attribute 'fit_class'

Tags: python, time-series, facebook-prophet

I am trying to use fbprophet have installed all required packages. Please refer to below package details.

```
Requirement already satisfied: fbprophet in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (0.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: Cython>=0.22 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from fbprophet) (0.29.21)
Requirement already satisfied: cmdstanpy==0.9.5 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from fbprophet) (0.9.5)
Requirement already satisfied: pystan>=2.14 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from fbprophet) (2.19.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.15.4 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from fbprophet) (1.19.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas>=1.0.4 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from fbprophet) (1.1.3)
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib>=2.0.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from fbprophet) (3.3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: LunarCalendar>=0.0.9 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from fbprophet) (0.0.9)
Requirement already satisfied: convertdate>=2.1.2 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from fbprophet) (2.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: holidays>=0.10.2 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from fbprophet) (0.10.4)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools-git>=1.2 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from fbprophet) (1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.8.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from fbprophet) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm>=4.36.1 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from fbprophet) (4.50.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.2 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pandas>=1.0.4->fbprophet) (2019.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow>=6.2.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib>=2.0.0->fbprophet) (8.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=2.0.3 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib>=2.0.0->fbprophet) (2.4.7)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib>=2.0.0->fbprophet) (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib>=2.0.0->fbprophet) (1.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2020.06.20 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib>=2.0.0->fbprophet) (2020.6.20)
Requirement already satisfied: ephem>=3.7.5.3 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from LunarCalendar>=0.0.9->fbprophet) (3.7.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pymeeus<=1,>=0.3.6 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from convertdate>=2.1.2->fbprophet) (0.3.7)
Requirement already satisfied: korean-lunar-calendar in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from holidays>=0.10.2->fbprophet) (0.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from holidays>=0.10.2->fbprophet) (1.15.0)
```

But while fitting model I am getting error "AttributeError: 'StanModel' object has no attribute 'fit_class'"

Can anyone please help me how to resolve this error

Also getting below warning when tried to load model

```
model = Prophet()
WARNING:pystan:No module named 'stanfit4anon_model_f5236004a3fd5b8429270d00efcc0cf9_4174861822198299618'
WARNING:pystan:Something went wrong while unpickling the StanModel. Consider recompiling.
```

Comment: Try re-installing first pystan and then fbprophet both with a --no-cache.

Comment: @AdamStrauss I tried re-installing pystan but not working. Also getting warning when tried to load model have added this in original question. Is it because of version issue under which StanModel pickle is generated .

Comment: @AdamStrauss I tried installing from Anaconda prompt "conda install -c conda-forge fbprophet" and able to fit model and run forecast from python. But still not sure what was the issue earlier why i was getting error earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Use `prophet` instead of `fbprophet` .

```
pip install pystan==2.19.1.1
pip install prophet
```